# Sigaction and SIGALRM

Tags: c

Hi I'm trying to learn more about signals and I wrote a simple code that supposed to just print "bye" everything the alarm signal is send. I am using sigaction to set this. However, I keep returning NULL in my error checking could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in Advance!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <sys/time.h>       /* for setitimer */
    #include <unistd.h>     /* for pause */
    #include <signal.h>     /* for signal */
    #define INTERVAL 500        /* number of milliseconds to go off */

    /* function prototype */
    void DoStuff();

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      struct itimerval it_val;  /* for setting itimer */
      struct sigaction sa;
      sa.sa_handler = &DoStuff;

      /* Upon SIGALRM, call DoStuff().
      * Set interval timer.  We want frequency in ms, 
      * but the setitimer call needs seconds and useconds. */
      if (sigaction(SIGALRM,&sa,NULL) < 0) { /*set the signal to be enabled if this action occurs*/
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
      }

      it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
      it_val.it_value.tv_sec =     INTERVAL/1000;
      it_val.it_value.tv_usec =    (INTERVAL*1000) % 1000000;   
      it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;
      if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) { /*set the timer to send the alarm command*/
        perror("error calling setitimer()");
        exit(1);
      }
    while(1)
    {
          pause();
    }


    }

    void DoStuff() {
      printf("bye\n");
    }
```

Comment: printf() is not signal-handler safe.

Comment: The posted code works fine for me.  What error are you seeing?

Comment: sigaction is always returning NULL

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: it turns out to be safe in this case, because main never calls any stdio routines (directly or indirectly) if it successfully starts up the signal handler and timer.  Buts that's admittedly unusual.

Comment: @SamuelMagaña: sigaction returns 0 on success and -1 on error.  NULL doesn't enter into it.

Comment: Sorry its always getting caught in my check to make sure it's not returning -1 @ChrisDodd

Comment: Strange -- it runs just fine for me on both Linux and OSX.  What system are you running on?

Comment: Sorry I think your right I reran my code on my Linux server and it's working fine. I was trying to run this on bash on windows. @ChrisDodd

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: On windows, you'd need some sort of POSIX emulator or subsytem to even compile this, in which case you need to make sure that is set up properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sigaction cannot return null, since it returns an integer. I'm assuming it's returning -1. You're not correctly initializing the sigaction structure. It has many fields, but you're allowing them to be undefined. Fix the structure definition and try again. See:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html