# How to make alarm safe?

Tags: c, printf, signals, alarm

[Sigaction and SIGALRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147464/sigaction-and-sigalrm)

On the above question, a comment says `printf() is not signal-handler safe.`

Could anybody show how to fix the program so that it is safe? Also, what does not safe mean here? Can anybody demonstrate how to make it fail?

Comment: Too broad. What specific manpage text is relevant to my question. What of bismon is relevant to my question?

Comment: You could also study the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell)